# How I can POST the value into input box?

Tags: javascript, php, html

**Intro**

I would like to get the current time after clicking at <kbd>click</kbd> and POST the value into input (text)box.

**Note**

Assume that bootstrap style sheet included.

`[input box]` <kbd>click</kbd>

**Date.php**

```
<form action="getTime.php" method="post">
      Date:&nbsp<input type="text" name="datetime" required>
                <button style="font-size:1em" type="submit" name="click" class="btn btn-info">click</button>
</form>
```

**getTime.php**

```
  if(isset($_POST['click']))
      {
          date_default_timezone_set('xxx/xxx); <!--xxx=any timezone-->
          $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
          //debugging
          //echo $date;
      }
```

**Expected result**

`[CURRENT TIME]` <kbd>click</kbd> -> show current time after clicking at <kbd>click</kbd>

Comment: It has to be the server time?  It won't be entirely accurate, because it takes time to send the response back to the browser, and by the time the response arrives, the "current time" will be off by some tenths of a second.  Alternatively you could use the client's clock which requires no server round-trip.  Depends on what you're doing.

Comment: I will suggest instead of calling PHP script on form submit use jQuery that will resolve you problem and give you better result. let me know if you need js code. 

Still you need to use PHP then use PHP session.

Comment: @Ankit Gupta Could you provide me js code please?, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code. It may help you.

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]) || isset($_POST["submit_x"]))   {
    $new_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['datetime']));
 echo $new_date;
}
```