# How can I POST the value into the input box using JQuery or Js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

From my earlier post ([How I can POST the value into input box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55612244/how-i-can-post-the-value-into-input-box)), one of the comment suggested me to do it in JQuery or Javascript.

More code and info, you can access it in the above link that I provided.

```
<label>Date</label>:&nbsp&nbsp
<input style="font-size:22px" size="20" type="text" name="datetime" value="" placeholder="Click to get current time." required readonly>

<button style="font-size:1em" type="submit" name="Time" class="btn btn-info">
  Click <i class="far fa-clock"></i>
</button>
```

After click at the button I expect that the value will be parsed into the input text box which I set it as `readonly` to prevent improper input from the user/admin.

Comment: What value are you expecting to put in the input on button click? As there is no code here for us to debug I would suggest you research the [`click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click) event handler, and using [`val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val) to update the value of your input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
 var today = new Date();
 var currentTimeValue = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate() + " " + today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
 $(".btn-info").click(function() {
    $("input").val(currentTimeValue);
 })
```

You should use ids in order to don't modify the first input inside the dom. (to avoid possible bugs )

Comment: This is the way, although I would not recommend to actually make the function trigger on the `btn-info` class. Neither would I recommend to change the `val` of every `input`

Comment: Is just an example. It is better to use an id

Comment: Yeah I know. Just commenting this in case OP would just copy paste this.

Comment: So, I have to set id in input tag? @AndreiLupuleasa

Comment: Yes and use like `$("#yourID").`

Comment: It worked but what if I have another input box above. What should I do?
<label>URL</label>:
<input class="form-group" style="font-size:22px" type="url" name="url" size="26" value="<?php echo $url; ?>" placeholder="URL (www.)">

<label>Date</label>:
<input style="font-size:22px" size="20" type="text" name="datetime" placeholder="Click to get current time." required readonly>
<button style="font-size:1em" type="submit" name="Time" id="id01"  class="btn btn-info">Click <i class="far fa-clock"></i></button> @AndreiLupuleasa

Comment: Use id selector instead of input.